# Mongoose Setting up Schema with Multiple Sub-Schemas using MERN Stack

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Requirements:

I am trying to create a quiz web application, the user should be able to add multiple quizzes. Each Quiz can have multiple questions with between 3-5 answers for each question. The way I have currently cofigured it is using Sub-Schemas however, as it is my first time using MERN stack and Mongoose, I am unsure how to populate and retrieve the information or know if I have done the Schema correctly.

This is the Schema:

```js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const { Schema } = require("mongoose");


const optionSubSchema = new Schema({
    value: {
      type: String,
    },
    index: {
      type: String,
      enum: ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"],
    },
  });

const answersSubSchema = new Schema({
  Option1: [optionSubSchema],
  Option2: [optionSubSchema],
  Option3: [optionSubSchema],
  Option4: [optionSubSchema],
  Option5: [optionSubSchema],
});


const questionsSubSchema = new Schema({
    value: {
      type: String,
    },
    Index: {
      type: Number,
    },
    answers: [answersSubSchema],
  });
  

const quizSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    description: {
      type: String,
    },
    questions: [questionsSubSchema],
  });
//exported with name 'quiz' for other modules to see it.

const Quiz = mongoose.model("quiz", quizSchema);
module.exports = Quiz;
```

This is the MOCKUP JSON RESPONSE I EXPECT FROM A GET REQUEST:

```js
{
  "Quiz1": [
    {
      "Question1": [
        {
          "Value": "Whats smallest number",
          "Index": "1",
          "Answers": [
            {
              "Option1": [
                {
                  "Index": "A",
                  "Value": "17"
                }
              ],
              "Option2": [
                {
                  "Index": "B",
                  "Value": "27"
                }
              ],
              "Option3": [
                {
                  "Index": "C",
                  "Value": "38"
                }
              ],
              "Option4": [
                {
                  "Index": "D",
                  "Value": "2"
                }
              ],
              "Option5": [
                {
                  "Index": "E",
                  "Value": "99"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "Question2": [
        {
          "Value": "Whats the biggest number",
          "Index": "1",
          "Answers": [
            {
              "Option1": [
                {
                  "Index": "A",
                  "Value": "17"
                }
              ],
              "Option2": [
                {
                  "Index": "B",
                  "Value": "27"
                }
              ],
              "Option3": [
                {
                  "Index": "C",
                  "Value": "38"
                }
              ],
              "Option4": [
                {
                  "Index": "D",
                  "Value": "2"
                }
              ],
              "Option5": [
                {
                  "Index": "E",
                  "Value": "99"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "Quiz2": [
    {
      "Question1": [
        {
          "Value": "How old am i!",
          "Index": "1",
          "Answers": [
            {
              "Option1": [
                {
                  "Index": "A",
                  "Value": "17"
                }
              ],
              "Option2": [
                {
                  "Index": "B",
                  "Value": "27"
                }
              ],
              "Option3": [
                {
                  "Index": "C",
                  "Value": "38"
                }
              ],
              "Option4": [
                {
                  "Index": "D",
                  "Value": "2"
                }
              ],
              "Option5": [
                {
                  "Index": "E",
                  "Value": "99"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "Question2": [
        {
          "Value": "How tall am i!",
          "Index": "1",
          "Answers": [
            {
              "Option1": [
                {
                  "Index": "A",
                  "Value": "17"
                }
              ],
              "Option2": [
                {
                  "Index": "B",
                  "Value": "27"
                }
              ],
              "Option3": [
                {
                  "Index": "C",
                  "Value": "38"
                }
              ],
              "Option4": [
                {
                  "Index": "D",
                  "Value": "2"
                }
              ],
              "Option5": [
                {
                  "Index": "E",
                  "Value": "99"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah! It looks ok! But the `index` field should be a `string` not a `number`